# rspec data scope between test and model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

I'm testing something like:

```
describe "#check_name" do
  it 'should raise ArgumentError with equal name' do
    @article = Factory.build(:article)
    @article.id = 3
    lambda { @article.check_name(@article.id) }.
      should raise_error(ArgumentError)
  end
end
```

And the model:

```
def check_name(article_id)
  tocheck = Article.find_by_id(article_id)
  if self.name == tocheck.name
    raise ArgumentError, "It has the same name!!!"
  end
end
```

Debugging the model, `self` has the values of the `Factory` `build`, it's ok. But `tocheck` is `nil`. `Article.find_by_id(article_id)` is nil.

If I'm calling `@article.check_name()` and the `Article` exists in the model, how is that is not possible to query?

Sorry, perhaps I don't understand the scope of the vars or the correct way to test this kind of code.

[UPDATE]
It's about the scope of the ActiveRecord's find operation.
What would be the correct way to test this raise?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord's `find` operations do database lookups and your `Article` object hasn't been saved to the database yet, hence the `nil` result.

While the Rails validation mechanisms may avoid the need to have a method like this and it's hard to specify what test approach would be best without seeing the whole model and it's constraints, I would think the choices are either:

- Use a test double to return the `find_by_id` results, or
- Create the record in the database instead of just "building it" and then build a new record with the same name, sending the `check_name` message to that new record

The latter might look like:

```
describe "#check_name" do
  it 'should raise ArgumentError with equal name' do
    article = Factory.create(:article)
    expect { Factory.build(:article).check_name(article.id) }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
  end
end
```

assuming your article factory uses the same name for all articles. If it doesn't, you have to pass the the name of the first article as an argument to the build of the second article.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know a good way to test this kind of code?